# Does PHP flush work with jQuerys ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, flush

I have created a page in which I use the PHP function flush(), to output data to the browser the second the data is echoed. I'm also calling this page using jQuery's ajax function. It works, but jQuery doesn't output anything until the entire page has executed, which kind of removes the functionality of flush().

How can I fix this?

My ajax call looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: url,
        data: postdata,
        success: function(retval) {
             jQuery('#retdiv").html(retval);
        }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Here you have 2 plugins for streaming:

*JQUERY AJAX HTTP STREAM* and *JSTREAMPLUG*.

http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/1840

"This plugin allows for a constant connection with a server keeping content continuously updated with the latest content using one http request. It extends the $.ajax, $.get, and $.post functions to allow for streaming."

Answer (score 0):

jQuery needs to wait for the connection to close before it can insert the html onto the page -- it can't display it progressively (it wouldn't make any sense).

Comment: Can you think of a different way to do it?

Comment: @MrAwesome What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MrAwesome: Sure, just send what you want to send, but include a key or marker, and just end the script. The client then sends back another request (with the marker), and your back-end script carries on processing the next step.

Comment: It does make sense. TS was referring to streaming/long-polling, and the common way to do it is indeed by flushing http-connection (xhr status-code = 3) without closing it, which unfortunately I don't believe to be supported by jQuery $.ajax at the moment, where the only supported event is "success" (status-code 4), i.e. when the connection is closed. There are other plugins to achieve what you're looking for if you google for long-polling