# Mootools: Why every flush() in PHP doesnt reflect at user side in mootools events

Tags: php, javascript, mootools, javascript-framework

i am developing an application in mootools.There is some code which sends request to server using Request class.

```
req = new Request({
async: false, method: 'post',

someEvent: function(currentChunk) 
{ /* this event is fired everytime when server flushes the output using flush()*/ },

  onSuccess: function(html) { responseProcessor(); },
  onFailure: function() { alert('Page Loading Failed ....!!'); },
});
```

At the server side, it executes a PHP file where i am flushing output buffer using
flush(). 
but at receiving end, there is onSuccess event which gives me whole responseData in one variable.

Is there any event which is fired after every single time server flushes the output buffer.?

Answer (score 1):

there is an progress event documented on the API: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request

Comment: I don't think with progress you can achieve this. It would be useful to show the download status of a static resource. And it's only supported by Gecko and WebKit (for me would be ok, but what if he needs something for IE :D )

Comment: did you tried? plus, there's nothing about static resources in your question, so i'm confused on what you want to track progress, and for what.

Comment: I didn't ask the question :) @Vin asked it.. I was only wondering if using "progress" event is possible to achieve what Vin is asking :)

Comment: In onProgress event, it can only display how much is loaded and how much its gunna load but doesnt display or gives what data is loaded till that moment.

Comment: ok so I read somewhere IE won't allow you to access the contents before it's fully loaded. Then, you can try to hack into mootools and retrieve the XHR's responseText property. you may google 'XMLHttpRequest readyState 3' to get further information

Answer (score 0):

The onSuccess callback passes the whole response as parameter. If you make an AJAX call, it returns as response all the stuff that would be rendered on the browser if you accessed that script directly. With mootools Request you can't show the progression of the output (there couldn't be events called after a flush). I don't know if there is a moo plugin that does something like this.

p.s.
I know there's a jQuery plugin that could do something for you ([Does PHP flush work with jQuerys ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276542/does-php-flush-work-with-jquerys-ajax))

Answer (score 0):

I checked the JQuery AJAX Http Stream plugin pointed out from the link steweb included in his anwser.

All it does is just a polling. You could extend the MooTools.Core.Request class and create a MooTools.Core.Request.Polling class which would add some options like the polling.

You will need to implement the 'request' event (triggered just before the request is sent) to set up the polling and the complete event to stop it.