# jQuery AJAX get PHP script, display the content as it loads

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook

I'm having to interact with the Facebook API for this project, which I find to be actually a bit slower than I expected.  Because of this, I'm having to do something which I find rather unorthodox: I need to load the content Facebook provides back in my PHP script AS IT LOADS from Facebook.  Traditionally I've loaded content into a div tag at the success of the script; however, I need to load the content as it appears.  It would be absolutely unacceptable to have a client wait nearly a minute for Facebook to load an album and all respective comments before displaying anything.  Hopefully I'm not being to vague; I'm not here to ask for code, but I've tried just about everything I can think of.  Is this a simple concept I'm missing?... I feel as though this is easier than I'm making it.

I'm using jQuery AJAX as I find this easiest to work with.  Any comments and/or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is that jQuery's AJAX methods hook into the `onreadystatechange` event and `readyState` variable.  `readyState` is only set to 4 when the file is completely transferred, and therefore your events will only fire after the download is complete.

Accessing the data as it is being sent is *not* consistent across different browser families.  Doing it this way is going to be incredibly complex and time-consuming.  I would recommend first doing this a little differently, perhaps by preloading the relevant facebook data on your own server predictively.  This can be compiled to a static page, and that can in turn be served to your users very quickly.

To get the data to your users faster, you'll need to work outside the box as well.  There's a jQuery plugin discussed here ( [Does PHP flush work with jQuerys ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276542/does-php-flush-work-with-jquerys-ajax) ) that makes jQuery ajax methods compatible with streamed output.  Good luck.

Comment: I took a look at the plugin mentioned, sadly the plugin sites that permission to access the responseText prematurely has been disallowed by most modern browsers since 2008 or so.  So I suppose the jig is up!  I've got to figure out another method of doing things.  I'd normally try to avoid them, but what would you think about using iframes here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to stem from the fact that you're getting too much data at once.  I suppose you are talking about receiving content from ajax as it is printed out immediately, but it is possible this content is built and sent at once and you won't have access to the data until the entire parse is complete.  If this is untrue, look into COMET.  If it is true, the solution is to put a limit on how much data you retrieve at once in an effort to reduce the parse time. For example, retrieve 5 photos in each request.  Add those 5 photos to the DOM while you retrieve the next 5.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting whatever code you want inside of the callback, just put it after the callback

for example

```
$("#div").load("facebook...", function() {
   //do stuff
});
//put the stuff you want to load at the same time, here
```